# ImportError : No module named setuptools

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I was installing mininet on my ubuntu 14.04.3 and during the installation, I got the error "ImportError : No module named setuptools". I tried to install it using sudo apt-get install python-setuptools and it shows that it is already the newest version. But still the installation fails.

For installing mininet I followed the steps on https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/master/INSTALL and tried the following commands

```
git clone git://github.com/mininet/mininet.git
 cd mininet
 git tag
 git checkout 2.2.1
 util/install.sh -n
```

then the installation ran and stopped in between showing the error.

Comment: And how were you installing `mininet`?

Comment: from installation instructions in the mininet github page

Comment: There are 4 options there. Which one did you pick? Please be specific.

Comment: native installation from source - the third option

Comment: It would be preferable if you [edit] your question and add the exact steps you followed instead of letting us look it up.

Answer (score 6):

Use this command to install necessary package

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
```

If the application is python2 use this instead

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

Comment: I did it and still I am getting the error during the installation.

Comment: Did you install python3-setuptools also?

Comment: I did not install python3-setuptools as I am having only python 2.7.5

Comment: install Python3-setuptools

Comment: Okay. Will that create any problem on my machine as other softwares on my machine require only python 2.7.5?

Comment: Co-existence of 2 & 3  doesn't cause any problem. Also be known that, the application decides which python is required.

Comment: I tried to install the python3-setuptools and got the following error ¨python3-setuptools : Depends: python3-pkg-resources (= 3.3-1ubuntu1) but 3.3-1ubuntu2 is to be installed¨ . I tried to install the missing dependency using apt-get install and it was a success. but when I try to install python3-setuptool, I am getting the same dependency error. Also I get an error that ¨E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.¨

Comment: Try to downgrade python3-pkg-resources using `sudo apt-get install python3-pkg-resources=3.3-1ubuntu1`

Comment: Thanks Anwar, It worked and now python3-setuptool is installed now. But still in the mininet installation, i am getting the error that ¨no module named setuptools¨

Comment: Use python3 explicitly. Use this command to install app `python3 util/install.sh -n`

Comment: it is giving an error ¨invalid syntax¨