# Trouble with evil limiter

Tags: python, port-forwarding

I'm pretty new to linux, and I am having trouble setting up the network control tool Evil limiter. When installing, I run into this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Command
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

Ive installed python3. Python. Python-pip. Python3-pip. Setuptools for both. Not sure where to go from here.
Ubuntu 19.04 with stock kernel. Whatever it installs with.

Comment: "No module named 'setuptools'" sjhould mean you did not install it "Setuptools for both. " are you sure? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426491/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-setuptools  and https://askubuntu.com/questions/830311/importerror-no-module-named-setuptools

Comment: I'm sorry, but we can't support hacking tools, or systems other than Ubuntu here. Excuse me if your intent is different.

Comment: @Rinzwind please tell me if my previous comment makes sense.

Comment: as long as the OS is Ubuntu questions about how to use software in it are ontopic.

Comment: What version Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes I sudo apt install python(3)-setuptools and there was no errors, however when I attempt to install evil limiter -for legitimate reasons, I'm testing usage on my home network- I keep getting thrown that setuptools error.  Ubuntu 19.04 and whatever kernel it installs by default.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
```

Try this, worked for me!